# HTML - Choose local path to move a file

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web-applications

I'm going to create a web app that's going to run locally on the user's computer.

First off, the user has downloaded a JSON file that ended up on "my download files" locally on their computer.

So they are going to browse to e.g myportal.local and there they are going to select the downloaded JSON file and also they need to choose a local location (directory).

To simply the workflow

1. Go to myportal.local in the browser
2. Choose in the form the JSON file
3. Choose a local path on the machine
4. Press submit and other scripts will parse and download things to the chosen folder.

Steps 1,2 and 4 is not a problem, it’s step 3 on how to choose a local destination.

Comment: `<form role="form" method="post" action="handleJson.php"><input type="file" value="choose a file" /><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`

Comment: Thank you, But the problem is to choose the local Plath

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this directly in the browser.

Since the HTTP server is running on the same computer, you could use server side code to examine the structure of the computer's file system and generate a user interface in HTML for the user to pick directories with.

Comment: Ah thank you, was thinking the same in the end.. hard to find the information tho.